# Issue regarding the deployment of a Meteor Application on Google Cloud App Engine: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED

Tags: docker, meteor, google-cloud-platform

TL;DR

Clone this: https://github.com/calvan-liang/radgrad2googlecloudissue.

Ensure you have meteor-google-cloud and gcloud CLI installed. If not:

On Powershell:

```
npm install meteor-google-cloud -g
```

On Ubuntu Terminal:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] 
https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --
keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

meteor-google-cloud --init
```

If not successful or not Ubuntu: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install

To deploy, in the app directory:

```
meteor-google-cloud --settings deploy/settings.json --app deploy/app.yml -- 
docker deploy/Dockerfile
```

What is the cause of the APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED and how can it be resolved?

.

.

.

.

.

Currently following the README.md from https://github.com/EducationLink/meteor-google-cloud to deploy a pre-existing project using Google Cloud. On the fourth step of deploy. While the default service is updating, I receive this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                                                throw(ex);
                                                ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [bla.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:406:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Pool.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7
    at callback (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Pre-existing project that is used is cloned from https://github.com/radgrad/radgrad2. I added a deploy directory in radgrad2/app. Inside the deploy directory, there are these files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
RUN install_node {{ nodeVersion }}
RUN npm install npm@{{ npmVersion }}
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
COPY . /app/
RUN (cd programs/server && npm install --unsafe-perm)
CMD node main.js
```

app.yml

```
runtime: custom
service: default
env: flex
threadsafe: true
zones:
- us-west3-b
- us-west3-c
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 20
network:
  session_affinity: true
automatic_scaling:
  max_num_instances: 2
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.dockerignore$
- ^(.*/)?\yarn-error.log$
- ^(.*/)?\.git$
- ^(.*/)?\.hg$
- ^(.*/)?\.svn$
```

settings.json

```
{
  "public": {},
  "private": {},
  "meteor-google-cloud": {
    "project": "radgrad2test",
    "stop-previous-version": "",
    "env_variables": {
      "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://user:pw@bla.com",
      "ROOT_URL": "https://example.de"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I am running this on Windows 10 Home using WSL 2 with Docker Desktop.

What may be possibly causing the app container to crash? How could I resolve this issue or where should I be looking to find the origin of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server

This was a bug that has [just recently being fixed](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/10976) in the newest Meteor version:

> In some MongoDB host providers like ScaleGrid and IBM Cloud some developers are getting this error because of certificate
>
> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [sg-meteorappdb-32194.servers.mongodirector.com:27017] on first connect [Error: self signed certificate

So in order to fix this, there has is now the option to configure Mongo options through your Meteor `settings.json` file. It is now [added to the documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_connection_options):

```
"packages": {
  "mongo": {
    "options": {
      "tls": true,
      "tlsCAFileAsset": "certificate.pem"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the above to the settings.json file and unfortunately it did not recognize ''certificate.pem". See below.

Comment: Please read the linked documentation on how to set the correct path to the pem file

Comment: My apologies. I couldn't resolve it. I have moved onto something a bit different. I think your answer was in the right direction. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. I added the above to the `settings.json` file and unfortunately it did not recognize ''certificate.pem"

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED
/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                                                throw(ex);
                                                ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/programs/server/assets/app/certificate.pem'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:243:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolveTLSOptions (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:241:34)
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:294:5
    at parseConnectionString (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:685:3)
    at connect (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:272:3)
    at /app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:215:5
    at maybePromise (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:719:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:211:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:421:22)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:206:11)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/app/programs/server/assets/app/certificate.pem'
}
```

What could I do to resolve this issue? I ensured that I installed the latest version of meteor.

Allowing invalid certificates does not work either. I run into the same `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [bla.com:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out` problem if I allow invalid certificates.